# VB - CefSharp not return values

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp

I can fill a value of a specific field with the code below

```
nav.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').value='teste';")
```

but I can't return the value of this field

```
Dim placeholder As Task(Of JavascriptResponse) = nav.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').value")
Task.WaitAll()
MsgBox(placeholder.Result.ToString)
```

both ***(placeholder.Result.ToString)*** and ***(placeholder.ToString)*** return ***"CefSharp.JavascriptResponse"***

Comment: As EvaluateScriptAsync returns Task it is recommended you use Await see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/await-operator#example

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the value from JavascriptResponse.Result property. Check the Success property first, if the script evaluation failed the error will be contained with the Message property.

http://cefsharp.github.io/api/97.1.x/html/Properties_T_CefSharp_JavascriptResponse.htm

Comment: when I do a return in the function and call the function in a struct, how do I call waiting for the async function to complete?

This way the sub prints the result before the asynchronous process ends.

Comment: Trying to call a method from within a struct sounds like a flaw in your design. I'd suggest rethinking your architecture. Ask a new question if you need input from others.

Answer (score 0):

I got it that way.

```
Public Async Function testeAsync() As Task(Of String)

    Dim placeholder2 As JavascriptResponse = Await nav.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').placeholder")

    If (placeholder2.Success) Then
        MsgBox(placeholder2.Result)
    End If

End Function
```

But when I do a return in the function and call the function in a struct, how do I call waiting for the async function to complete?

This way the sub prints the result before the asynchronous process ends.

```
Sub testeResultado()
    Dim returnedTaskTResult As Task(Of String) = testeAsync()
    MsgBox(returnedTaskTResult.ToString)
End Sub
```